# Ajax autocomplete search not displaying result list after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

Here is my issue that I'm facing on Ajax autocomplete search. When I'm typing something on textbox its showing list of result perfectly. But when I reload the page and type for first time on textbox the list of result is not showing. Again if I backspace the text and retype, the result is showing on result list. This issue is not specific to any browser. I am not getting the cause of issue.

```
    var locationSearchListData = [];
    var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
    var postData = '{cultureId : "DE"}';
    // Ajax call to run webservice's methods.
    $.ajax({
        url: "/asmx/SearchLocations.asmx/GetAutoCompleteSearchLocations",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (responseData) {
            if (responseData != undefined && responseData != null && responseData.d.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < responseData.d.length; i++) {
                    // Add resopnse data in location search lis, this list is used as a source for autocomplete textbox.
                    locationSearchListData.push({
                        label: responseData.d[i].locationData,
                        latitude: responseData.d[i].latitude,
                        longitude: responseData.d[i].longitude
                    });
                }
            }
            $(".autosearch").autocomplete({
                // Set source for textbox, this source is used in autocomplete search. 
                source: locationSearchListData,
                // Set required minimum length to display autocomplete list.
                minLength: 3,
                // Set required delay time to display autocomplete list.
                delay: 500,
                // Define selection method displaying results for the location selected.
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    // Get the current selected item from the autocomplete list.
                    $(this).val(ui.item);
                    // Call display selected item for currently selected element.                        
                    displaySelectedItem(ui.item);
                },
                // Handle the autocomplete search suggestions menu opening. 
                open: function () {
                    // This method is used to highlight the searched text in the search items. 
                    $('ul: li: a[class=ui-corner-all]').each(function () {
                        // Get each text value. 
                        var text1 = $(this).text();
                        // Get user input from the search box.                            
                        var val = $("#<%= txtOrtOderPlz.ClientID %>").val();
                        // Get the regular expression to match.  
                        re = new RegExp(val, "i");
                        // Match with the regular expression value.
                        matchNew = text1.match(re);
                        // Find the reg expression, replace it with bold font.
                        text = text1.replace(matchNew, ("<span style='font-weight:bold;color:#4D4D4D;'>") + matchNew + ("</span>"));
                        // Add the cutomised html in autocomplete searchlist.
                        $(this).html(text);
                    });
                },
                // On every search clear the data.
                search: function (event, ui) {
                    // Clear results when no location found.                     
                    $("#<%= hdnSearchResultLatitude.ClientID %>").val('');
                    $("#<%= hdnSearchResultLongitude.ClientID %>").val('');
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Check for your positioning of jquery link on page.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I put jquery link inside head tag of master page. I checked by putting the link on ascx page also, where my autocomplete textbox is present, but still facing the same issue.